# <!--[if lte IE 8]> condional comment not working on wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

Wordpress site, theme falls apart if Internet Explorer 8 or lower, wanted to add conditional comment with style to display none of body, just as temp fix but style is not being applied when ie8 or lower, added code to header.php file.

Any suggestions? Thx!

```
<head>
<!-- Title -->
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>

<!-- Meta -->
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Favicon-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php $favicon=th_theme_data('favicon'); echo esc_url($favicon['url']); ?>" type="image/x-icon">

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"/>
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type='text/css'>
    body {display:none!important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->

<?php wp_head() ?>
</head>
```

Here's what rendered HTML looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US" > <!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type='text/css'>
    body {display:none!important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->

<head>
<!-- Title -->
<title>_1stDraft | Rogers &amp; Cowan</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Favicon-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="" type="image/x-icon">

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"/>
<link rel="pingback" href="http://wprogerscowan.build.webershandwick.com/xmlrpc.php" />

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type='text/css'>
    body {display:none!important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Do you *really* need to support IE 8 (or 7 or 6)?  You could just drop support for IE < 9 and save yourself a ton of trouble!

Comment: We need more info here.  What does "not working" mean?  What does your `header.php` look like?  Can you make a small example code snippet you can show us?

Comment: Don't really need support but happen to view the site on a machine still running ie8 and it looked terrible... By not working, I meant that the conditional comment did not apply the style wanted.

Comment: I don't think many people *happen* to still be using IE 8 (don't quote me, I don't know the actual numbers).

Comment: Can you show us your code, or at least a small example we could test out?

Comment: In your example, you forgot the `<![endif]-->` (not sure if that's just a typo/copy & paste error, though).  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: just updated snippet

Comment: I made a small example (http://jsbin.com/hacudezige/edit?html), and it seems to work for me in IE 8 (view at: http://output.jsbin.com/hacudezige).  Maybe something else is wrong?  What is the *rendered* HTML?  Maybe there is some invalid HTML?

Comment: added rendered html, also do not have access to the machine running ie8 and cannot test anymore...

Comment: Virtual Machines FTW: https://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/

Comment: Could you possibly test for me? I'm on a work computer and can't install without admin

Comment: IE8 has a really stupid and infuriating behaviour: if you access it through your intranet, it pretends it's IE7. There is no way for the web site to override this behaviour.

Comment: @PaulTomblin I'm not sure that explains the OP's problem. IE7 would also respond to the conditional comment. I just tested with IE7.

Comment: @newb101 Is the site live yet?

Comment: @MrLister it probably doesn't explain his problem, but it's yet another reason why cutting support for any IE < 10 is the greatest day in a web developer's life.

Comment: site is not live, but i have a link a password to view if anyone can check it out